# Restart SQL Server if I change max pool size?

Tags: sql-server-2012, connection-string, connection-pooling

If I change "Max Pool Size" in my connection string, do I need to restart SQL Server for the change to take effect?

Comment: Are you settings this setting for your application? If so, then no, you don need to restart sql server.

Comment: No, the ADO.NET max pool size is a **client-side** setting - the client pools up to that many connections to the server. Changing the max pool size doesn't affect the server in any way - no server reboot required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a connection is first opened, a connection pool is created based on an exact matching algorithm that associates the pool with the connection string in the connection. Each connection pool is associated with a distinct connection string. **When a new connection is opened, if the connection string is not an exact match to an existing pool, a new pool is created.**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx